# Problem While Getting All of Input Values

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I entered Jquery very fast and I m having trobule.I m trying to get all input value and alert them.But i get only first input.Also I need to put span because input should be draggable.Where I m doing.I hope you ll answer it

```
<label>Paragraph</label>
<span class="blue">
<div id="page"></div>
</span>
<script>
$("label").click(function(){
$("#page").append('<span class="blue"><input  type="text" /></input></div></span>');
$(".blue").draggable();
$("#page").droppable();
});
$("#page").dblclick(function(){
var panel= $("#page .blue");
var inputs = panel.find("input");
alert(inputs.val());
});
</script>
```

or the other style

```
<p></p>
<label>Paragraph</label>
<span class="blue">
<div id="page"></div>
</span>
<script>
$("label").click(function(){
$("#page").append('<span class="blue"><input  type="text" /></input></div></span>');
$(".blue").draggable();
$("#page").droppable();
});
$("#page").dblclick(function(){
alert($("#page input").val());
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Niklas said, you want to use `each()` here. Here's an example, based off of your original code:

```
$("label").click(function() {
    $("#page").append('<div><input type="text" value="foo" class="fooBox" /></div>');
});

$("#page").dblclick(function(){
    $('.fooBox').each(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pGxjz/1/) where you can try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop through each input. Like this:

```
var inputs = panel.find("input");
$(inputs).each(function(i,e){
  alert($(e).val());
});
```

Comment: You answered while I was making a jsFiddle for it, so I upvoted you :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your previous post plus this one, you seem to have a misunderstanding of how jQuery selectors work.

`alert($("#page input").val());` will not work, because `$("#page input")` returns a collection of every element that is an `input` inside of the `page` element.

There are some actions you can call on this that will apply to every item in the collection. Such as `$("div.page").css('background-color','red');` - this will apply a red background color to every `div` with a class of `page` without the need to iterate over them individually.

But there are some actions that can not apply to the collection, and will only choose the last (or first, I cant remember which) item in the collection. For example, what you are trying to do: `alert($("#page input").val());` will only alert one value. Because `.val()` must be applied only to one single element. Not an entire collection. So wehn you call it on the entire collection, it will only return the `.val()` for one of them.  To alert every value, you need to iterate over the collection.

Comment: +1 thanks for trying to address the OP's underlying misunderstanding.